# Android Firestore update field value if item exist in database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If the value in the database already exist (for example I want to add Cheetos to firestore and in the database cheetos already exist) then I want to update the quantity field of that item. I make the code like this but the app still add new item when the value is the same. I think the system doesn't detect my `'if(task.getResult().getDocuments().size()>0'`.

this is the firestore data [image]

this is the method code

```
private void uploadItem() {
        merk = etMerk.getText().toString().trim();
        type = etType.getText().toString().trim();
        typemerk = merk + " - " + type;
        qty = etQty.getText().toString().trim();
        price = etPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        date = datetime.getText().toString();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        db.collection("watchlist").whereEqualTo("merk",typemerk)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult().getDocuments().size()>0){
                                Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Barang Sama", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());
                                    String itemid = document.getString("id");
                                    String date = document.getString("date");
                                    String type = document.getString("type");
                                    String Oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                                    String price = document.getString("price");

                                    int sum= Integer.parseInt(Oldqty) + Integer.parseInt(qty);
                                    String newQty = String.valueOf(sum);

                                    Map<String, Object> newstock = new HashMap<>();
                                    newstock.put("qty",newQty);

                                    FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                    database.collection("watchlist")
                                            .document(itemid).update(newstock).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Berhasil Menambahkan jumlah barang", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            etMerk.setText("");
                                            etType.setText("");
                                            etQty.setText("");
                                            etPrice.setText("");
                                            etMerk.setFocusable(true);
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Gagal Memasukkan stok, silahkan coba lagi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                }
                                            });

                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                upload();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing Cheetos in your code, Where are you updating Cheetos Value in Firestore can you add that code?? Also, data from Firebase Firestore can help us understand the issue..

Comment: @Fire-In-D-Hole this is only the upload method,  the value that will be upload to the database is from Edit Text field, in this case the "cheetos" value is already stored in String typemerk. I already add image about the firestore data

Comment: Are you generating another id when you upload the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works

```
private void cutStock() {
        merk = etMerk.getText().toString().trim();
        type = etType.getText().toString().trim();
        typemerk = type + " - " + merk;
        qty = etQty.getText().toString().trim();
        price = etPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        date = datetime.getText().toString();
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference documentReference = db.collection("watchlist");
        final CollectionReference documentSales = db.collection("sales");


        documentReference.whereEqualTo("type",typemerk)
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                        String id = document.getString("id");
                        String oldqty = document.getString("qty");
                        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(oldqty) - Integer.parseInt(qty);
                        String newQty = String.valueOf(i);

                        Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("qty",newQty);
                        db.collection("watchlist").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());

                        Map<String, Object> sales = new HashMap<>();
                        sales.put("date", date);
                        sales.put("type", typemerk);
                        sales.put("qty", qty);
                        sales.put("price", price);



                        documentSales.add(sales).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Berhasil mencetak transaksi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                etMerk.setText("");
                                etType.setText("");
                                etQty.setText("");
                                etPrice.setText("");
                            }
                        })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Gagal mencetak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                });
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            }
            else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Barang tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```